# A word for the state of being a johnny-on-the-spot

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or short phrase (something a bit catchy, maybe) that evokes a state of being a useful to the point of being indispensable. This entity has become so integral to the process that it cannot be removed without great disruption, and are the defacto go-to when new needs arise. Words that are close but not quite: "embedded", "enmeshed". "Sticky" has also been suggested, but I'm looking for something with a more positive connotation.

Comment: A person or thing? Context is what helps us help you.

Comment: There are various terms for an essential person for their employer (some are gender-specific too). There are also terms for an object which has many functions, and for an object which holds everything together, and an object which is necessary for some purpose. But I'm not listing them all. Do you want an adjective or a noun? Can you provide a sentence it will fit in? Do you want a slang, colloquial or formal term?

Comment: Irreplaceable? Intuitive? A star?

Comment: What’s wrong with *indispensable*?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you've already got the word: integral. Perhaps your snag is the way you're currently constructing your sentence. "This entity has become so integral to the process that..." - by using "so" you're giving the impression that there are different degrees of being integral, but "integral" is an absolute. Something is either integral or it isn't. The dictionary definition runs thus: 'necessary to make a whole complete; essential or fundamental'.